# I cannot create new C project in Eclipse:No project types available. Project cannot be created

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide

I had installed Eclipse IDE for Java on my Windows 10 laptop then I have uploaded it for C/C++ and using Open Perspective I have replaced Java with C/C++.

Now I cannot create new C project in Eclipse IDE. New -> File -> Create C/C++ Project -> C Managed Build -> then when I write first letter in the project name field it says: No project types available. Project cannot be created.

The same happens when I try it for C++.

[This is what happened when I try to name my new C project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI7uR.png)

Comment: Your installation still lacks bits yo use the C/C++ peespective.  You will need to download these (Help-> Install new software).  Worst case, you can download the eclipse for C/C++ of the same version and dump it on top of the Java.

Comment: I did exactly how you told me - I have installed new software and now it works.

Comment: But I had installed a new software before I asked here for the solution as it didn't work. It seems I didn't tick the right tools: autotools, development tools, and developments tools SDK. I have followed the instructions from this YT tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhCLgRVcKMg and it led me to the successful solution. Thank you very much.